# Running one OS of a dual boot system as a VM guest of the other OS

Tags: virtualbox, multi-boot, windows-11, ubuntu-22.04

I have a machine which has one installation of Windows on one drive and one installation of Ubuntu on another drive, which I can select during boot via a boot menu.

This way I have to decide which OS I want to use before booting.

What I want to do now is to boot into Windows, set up a VirtualBox VM guest which uses the Ubuntu from the other disk as its operating system.

I would create a rawdisk vmdk which "points" to the partition of the Ubuntu installation and use that vmdk to create the VM.

In theory this should be possible, but issues could arise. For example the Ubuntu installation was installed on the real hardware and would then run on a virtualized machine with very different properties. I'm not sure if Ubuntu can deal with this, but I think there's a good chance of it working.

This way I could use both OSs at the same time, while Ubuntu would run at a somewhat degraded performance, which would be OK. I just don't want to reboot and switch OS for every minor modification I want to do to the Ubuntu installation.

When I would want to use the full potential of the Ubuntu installation, for example having it access the GPU, then I would boot into Ubuntu and not use Windows at all during that time.

I haven't tried it because there's a risk of damaging the Ubuntu installation, so I'd like to know if this can be done without worries.

Comment: @John Thanks but this is of no use for me, as I would have two separate Ubuntu installations. I want the modifications which I do in the VM be applied directly onto the one which I can dual-boot into.

Comment: @John Most drivers are provided by the kernel, one same kernel that you use on different machine, virtual or not. Neither do OOT drivers prevent you from using an installation on a machine that do not use them. Even the most significant libGL conflict brought by the NVIDIA proprietary driver has been addressed by libglvnd, IIRC.

Comment: @John, Linux is not like windows when it comes to drivers.  It is usually entirely practical to take a disk with Linux and put it in another computer and have it "just work" (as long as the architectures are the same - eg x86).  There may be some gotchas arround the initial process to getting to grub/uefi, but after that its fairly easy.  VM's don't have an issue here.